# How to launch Git Bash inside the NppExec Console

Tags: git-bash, nppexec

The NppExec Console supports running the Windows command shell within the console by simply running `cmd` within the console.  Is there a way to launch Git Bash inside the NppExec Console?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like git bash is always started in its own console window. For example, if you start cmd.exe and type e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
```

in it, you'll see the git bash is started in its own console window anyway (even though cmd itself has a console window).
Basing on that, you can *start* git bash from NppExec's Console, but it will be *running* in its own console window.